# How to add custom methods to transformations

Tags: kentico

How would you write code like this as a custom method to transformations using kentico 11?

```
        <li class="<%#Eval("DocumentMenuClass")%>"> 
         <a href="<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DocumentMenuJavascript"))!=""? "#" :Convert.ToString(Eval("DocumentMenuRedirectUrl"))!=""? Eval("DocumentMenuRedirectUrl"):GetDocumentUrl() %>" <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DocumentMenuRedirectUrl"))!=""? "target="+"_blank":""%>  <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DocumentMenuJavascript"))!=""? "onclick="+"javascript:"+Eval("DocumentMenuJavascript"):""%>>
            <span><%# IfCompare(Eval("DocumentMenuCaption"),"",Eval("DocumentMenuCaption"),Eval("DocumentName"))%></span>
          </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to add a custom transformation method is described in the [documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/k11/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/adding-custom-methods-to-transformations). Then, the actual logic of that custom method is up to you.